# Testing sample bias

Tags: bias, sample

How do I test for sample bias between 2 groups within a sample? i.e. those who provided consent vs those who did not provide their consent to share their data?

Comment: Do you some sort of data for everyone who did not consent to share their data? For example, the number of Males and Females that were approached, and whether or not they consented (and the rest of the data if they did consent). If you have no record of those who did not consent, then adjusting for sampling bias is challenging, but may still be possible. For example, if you know that the population is 50% Male and 50% Female, but your sample is 80-20, then you can use some reweighting techniques to rebalance the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have the population data to weigh it. The two groups have unequal sample sizes of about 90% Vs 10%. Will doing a simple chi-sq test for the responses n demographics allow me to see if there are sig. Diff between the two grps? If there isn't, they are not sig. diff. With that can I say they are not bias?

Comment: "Sample Bias" normally refers to the difference between the population and the sample. If you don't know about either the population or the people who were contacted but refused to be in the sample, then I don't think there's anything you can do about sample bias. You can test for responses vs demographics, which will show you if there's a relation in the sample. But that isn't really about sample bias. Having a non-significant result is not evidence there is no sample bias.